# I fail to access Resource image file from code in WPF using pack Uri

Tags: c#, wpf, resources

I have some image resources in my app i want to access programaticly.

Now i'm based on some source code so i need to acess via Uri so my code is :

```
new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/YearBook;component/Resources/Output/" + i.ToString() + ".jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

though when i try to access it i get error that resources not found ( and the name is right)

Anyone knows why?

**EDIT:**

Might be i needed to add some assembly in the assembly file?

Comment: You need to provide more information. Is the assembly `YearBook` available? Are the images embedded into the assembly as "resource" or "embedded resource"? (Only one of the two is correct, not sure which exactly.) Is the assembly `YearBook` located in the same folder as the executable (or in a subfolder `YearBook`)?

Comment: Yes to all and it's a resource

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end with all types of ways to approach this resource, my problem was i forgot 1 folder in the sub folders.

This code eventually worked :

```
new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/Images/Output/" 
+ i.ToString() + ".jpg", UriKind.Absolute)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
StreamResourceInfo resource = Application.GetResourceStream(
new Uri("SilverlightApp1;component/embedded.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

SilverlightApp1 is assembly name,component is keyword .You will  get your resource and then cast it to appropriate type, Hope this will help.

Comment: in the end it needs to be BitmapImage, i tried setting Stream of a bmp to an stream from the essambly but that failed to work, it would be easier getting a the uri of a resource, how can i cast it? By the way, when i try your code i get the same error.