# How to bundle index.html, jquery.js, main.css in DLL to use in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dll, resources

I know that possible **to bundle**

eg.

```
index.html
main.css
jQuery.js
Logo.gif
```

into an assembly (DLL) and use it in WPF via `res://` protocol, but I cannot find any project template in Visual Studio 2010/2012 to do it.

How it is possible to do this?

Comment: Your intent is completely unclear. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @HighCore I want to put simple web page into dll and using res:// protocol open  this page via WPF WebBrowser control. That's it.

Comment: How would the `WebBrowser` control load the data from the resource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to create what is called **Resource File**. There is wizard for creating this type of file:

**File** -> **New** -> **File** -> **C#** -> **Resource File** on my VS2010.

Comment: Could u tell me how do I can access index.html in that file? I need to access it in WPF. Thank you!

Comment: @Peretz http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970494.aspx, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9420767 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665764 ...

Comment: @NemanjaBoric: that's not exactly helpful for the `WebBrowser` control.

Comment: @sixlettervariables perhaps this is more helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254605, or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934357/how-to-load-html-javascript-from-embedded-resource-into-winform-web-browser. In any case, there is lot of resources (hah!) available for researching more.

Comment: wb.Navigate("res://WpfApplication12.exe/index.html"); it is not working but index,html is under main resource file...